# Move the carousel under the menu in response

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with bootstrap and on the top of my package I have two menu.
In the menu over the carousel I have one button search and one link with border-radius  which in response the are over the carousel but I don't want that they be like that.

Please can help someone to move the  carousel  under the menu in the response?

Comment: Please share the relevant HTML/CSS that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Post a sample of your code here, or create a fiddle with your problem ( jsfiddle.net)... Probably you'll just need to play with their *z-indexes*, or use Bootstrap's fixed top menu (which has absolute positioning) with a hack to prevent scroll.